# VSCode REST client : how to get now date

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client, vscode-restclient

I am doing some request with rest client extension in VScode
I would like to know if there is a way to get the current date and to use it in a request

It would be something like

```
# CreateLesson
# @name CreateLesson
POST {{baseUrl}}/Lesson/CreateLesson HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}

{
    "Name": "Maths",
    "DateCreation": {{__now__}},
    "Room": "B23"
    "NbHours": 2,
}
###
```

Do you know how to do it please?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works

```
###

@authToken = {{tokenAPI.response.body.token}}
@createdAt = {{$datetime iso8601}}

###
# CreateLesson
# @name CreateLesson
POST {{baseUrl}}/Lesson/CreateLesson HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}

{
    "Name": "Maths",
    "DateCreation": "{{createdAt}}",
    "Room": "B23"
    "NbHours": 2,
}
###
```